# improving my jquery image carousel

Tags: jquery

I have built my own jquery image carousel (with a lot of help from most of you guys) and it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/2C8fy/33/

I'd like to improve it. The problem that I'm facing right now is that when you click the buttons too rapidly, the images start to pile up. What is the best way to prevent this? Should I use some kind of timer or is there a JQuery function that I can easily insert somewhere? I am still learning JQuery and I just want to know what direction to take. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of stop() before animating:

```
.stop(true,true).animate()
```

Comment: whats the meaning of `true,true` ?